# KrbException "Message Stream Modified (41)" when connecting to SMB share using Kerberos

Tags: java, kerberos, samba, cifs, jcifs

I'm having some issues with Kerberos authentication to perform file management with JCifs (Kerberos extension version 1.3.17)

This is my current configuration of krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = <REALM_NAME_UPPERCASE>
    udp_preference_limit = 1
[realms]
    <REALM_NAME_UPPERCASE> = {
        kdc = <DOMAIN_NAME_UPPERCASE>:88
        admin_server = <DOMAIN_NAME_UPPERCASE>
        default_domain = <DOMAIN_NAME_UPPERCASE>
    }
[domain_realm]
    .<domain_name> = <REALM_NAME_UPPERCASE>
    <domain_name> = <REALM_NAME_UPPERCASE>
[appdefaults]
    kinit = {
        renewable = true
        forwardable = true
    }
```

And this is code authenticating the user and then trying to find a file on a fileserver in the network:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:/krb5.conf");
    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

    Map<String, Object> state = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    state.put("javax.security.auth.login.name", "USERNAME");
    state.put("javax.security.auth.login.password", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());

    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("debug", "true");
    options.put("useFirstPass", "true");

    Krb5LoginModule login = new Krb5LoginModule();
    login.initialize(subject, null, state, options);

    if (login.login()) {
        login.commit();
    }

    String path = "file://HOST/242269/"; // existing file server folder
    Kerb5Authenticator kerberosAuthenticator = new Kerb5Authenticator(subject);

    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, kerberosAuthenticator);
    SmbFile[] files = smbFile.listFiles();

    for (SmbFile file : files) {
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code, it says it can authenticate the user with those credentials (when I change the credentials, authentication fails) and it creates a ticket for this user.
When I later on try to retrieve the content of a file directory over CIFS, it gives me the following error:

```
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
at jcifs.smb.SpnegoContext.initSecContext(SpnegoContext.java:80)
at jcifs.smb.Kerb5Authenticator.setup(Kerb5Authenticator.java:196)
at jcifs.smb.Kerb5Authenticator.access$000(Kerb5Authenticator.java:30)
at jcifs.smb.Kerb5Authenticator$1.run(Kerb5Authenticator.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at jcifs.smb.Kerb5Authenticator.sessionSetup(Kerb5Authenticator.java:166)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:320)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:239)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:925)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:974)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:890)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.resolveDfs(SmbFile.java:669)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:783)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doFindFirstNext(SmbFile.java:2009)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1758)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1735)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1668)
```

You can find the complete error log [here](http://www.pastebin.ca/2531731) (some details are obfuscated)

Could someone please get me going in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Another (useful?) comment: This user account does not have access to the root of the fileserver, only to that specific subfolder. I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: Try to put your krb5.conf and login.conf files inside lib folder of your tomcat and try again.

Answer (score 17):

**Uppercase** of the realm is very important to avoid "`Exception: krb_error 41 Message stream modified (41)`".

**See** http://sourceforge.net/p/spnego/discussion/1003769/thread/99b3ff67/

Comment: Could you be more specific in your answer please and address (preferably with code) how your suggestion could help the asker? Explain it a bit more, please. I (as a reader) find it difficult to understand how your answer is a solution. Posting a link is more suitable as a comment in my humble opinion.

Comment: The problem is that Kerberos checks the integrity of the answer by calculating a checksum based on pasword and parameters. If the received answer was positive but the input parameters do not match it gives this "stream modified" error. And the most likely cause for that is that the server used the real as uppercase stream while the client used it lowercase.

Comment: This general error can certainly be caused by this in some environments. I have no idea _why_, though.

Answer (score 16):

Hate to necrobump but ran into the same problem when launching Spark and Zeppelin inside a Docker container, with the master being a remote Kerberos-enabled YARN cluster. However, in this case, the realm name uppercase/lowercase was **not** the problem.

After a few hours, I found [this thread](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=17000) which suggests removing the following line from the `krb5.conf` file:

```
renew_lifetime = 7d
```

And that solved the issue. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Worked for me too after removing that line.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (and **better**) answer to removing the `renew_lifetime = 7d` line in the config, is by **allowing** the principal to do renewals. In CentOS 7, an example command would be the following:

```
kadmin -p admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
```

where I assume that `admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM` is the Administrator principal, then:

```
modprinc -maxrenewlife 90day +allow_renewable your_service@EXAMPLE.COM
```

where I assume the principal for the service that causes the problems is `your_service@EXAMPLE.COM`; and the `90day` renew life is arbitrary.

**This solves the issue *without* removing the `renew_lifetime=7d` from the `krb5.conf` file!**